# How to proxy pass some URLs to one place, and the rest elswhere, in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have several web apps hosted in tomcat. I use Nginx to proxy pass requests to them. I want to send all the requests to one app when url doesn't match with the other app urls. I wrote a Nginx config like this.

```
server { 
    listen 80;

    root /home/ubuntu/example/example_website;
    server_name example.com;

    expires -1;
    location /dashboard {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dashboard;
    }

    location /mobile {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/mobile;
    }
    location /try {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/try;
    }
    location /trial {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/trial;
    }
    location /registration {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/registration;
    }

    location /widget {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/widget;
    }
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/urlMapper;
    }

}
```

Requests to other apps works fine. But requests are not send to urlMapper default app. Please help me to correct this.

Comment: Did you check the log?

Comment: Set the access_log and share logs here please